# if statement runtime error

Tags: c++, if-statement, runtime-error

I originally had 3 equations: Pu, Pm & Pd. It ran fine.
Once I introduced the `if` statement, with variations on the 3 equations, depending on the loop iteration, I receive a runtime error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers in advance.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>


int Rounding(double x)
{
    int Integer = (int)x;
    double Decimal = x - Integer;

    if (Decimal > 0.49)
    {
        return (Integer + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return Integer;
    }
}

int main()
{
double a = 0.1;
double sigma = 0.01;
int delta_t = 1;
double M = -a * delta_t;
double V = sigma * sigma * delta_t;
double delta_r = sqrt(3 * V);
int count;

double PuValue;
double PmValue;
double PdValue;

int j_max;
int j_min;

j_max = Rounding(-0.184 / M);
j_min = -j_max;

std::vector<std::vector<double>> Pu((20), std::vector<double>(20)); 
std::vector<std::vector<double>> Pm((20), std::vector<double>(20)); 
std::vector<std::vector<double>> Pd((20), std::vector<double>(20)); 

std::cout << std::setprecision(10); 
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        for (int j = i; j >= -i; j--)   
            {
                count = count + 1;
                if (j = j_max) // Exhibit 1C
                {   
                    PuValue = 7.0/6.0 + (j * j * M * M + 3 * j * M)/2.0;
                    PmValue = -1.0/3.0 - j * j * M * M - 2 * j * M;
                    PdValue = 1.0/6.0 + (j * j * M * M + j * M)/2.0;
                }   
                else if (j = j_min) // Exhibit 1B
                {   
                    PuValue = 1.0/6.0 + (j * j * M * M - j * M)/2.0;
                    PmValue = -1.0/3.0 - j * j * M * M + 2 * j * M;
                    PdValue = 7.0/6.0 + (j * j * M * M - 3 *  j * M)/2.0;
                }   
                else
                {
                    PuValue = 1.0/6.0 + (j * j * M * M + j * M)/2.0;
                    PmValue = 2.0/3.0 - j * j * M * M;
                    PdValue = 1.0/6.0 + (j * j * M * M - j * M)/2.0;
                }
                Pu[count][i] = PuValue;
                Pm[count][i] = PmValue;
                Pd[count][i] = PdValue;

                std::cout << Pu[count][i] << ", ";
            }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning instead of checking for equal: `j_max` to `j` in your if statements.

```
if (j = j_max)
//    ^

else if (j = j_min)
//         ^
```

Change `if (j = j_max)` to `if (j == j_max)`,
And `else if (j = j_min)` to `else if (j == j_min)`.

Comment: You are awesome Andreas. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Correct the following `if` conditional check and all other instances of an `if` check

```
if(j=j_max)

with 

if (j == j_max)
```

you are checking for an equality not assigning.

Your code was going into an infinite loop.